# How i can integrate Yodlee IAV?

Tags: php, verification, account, yodlee, instant

### I want to integrate Yodlee Instant Account Verification to my site.

i am newbie Please mentions the steps. i am using PHP.
My requirement is to verify 
 1. User Bank Account Number
 2. Account Name
 3. Bank routing Number
 4. Address
For registration on my site. 
Kindly Please mention in detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can register on `developer.yodlee.com` Then you can go through the [quickstart guide](http://developer.yodlee.com/Instant_Account_Verification_API/IAV_Quickstart) for IAV to get started. Also you need to go through [API reference](http://developer.yodlee.com/Instant_Account_Verification_API/IAV_Services_Guide/IAV_REST_API_Reference) page.

You can also go through the [IAV](http://developer.yodlee.com/Instant_Account_Verification_API) page . Also use the [testdrive tool](http://developer.yodlee.com/TestDrive) to test the APIs.

Yodlee do provide account number, account name and routing number but address of the user is not provided.